# How to remove first 3 bytes of buffer

Tags: c++

How would you remove first 3 bytes of a buffer in C++?

In javascript I would simply:

```
var hashed = new Buffer(packet, "hex");

// remove first 3 bytes from packet
hashed = hashed.slice(3);
```

Example:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06
```

Output:

```
04 05 06
```

My C++ code:

```
size_t size = node::Buffer::Length(packet->ToObject());
char *buf = node::Buffer::Data(packet->ToObject());
```

Node.js code (usage):

```
var addon = require('./build/Release/krypto');

console.log(addon.encrypt( new Buffer("3A00F063F9757D6FE7ABD8ABCE8387C8C14F43CDE1DAA64D195BB8", "hex") ));
```

Comment: what does your buffer look like?

Comment: how does the code until the trimming look in your C++ program?

Comment: I don't get the down votes :\ updated my question with code.

Comment: use `std::string` and then `std::string::substr()`

Comment: `node::Buffer::Length(packet->ToObject())` - what are all these classes?  Are you using some library?  It's hard to give a good answer when we don't know the API for the objects....

Comment: @Víctor: Because it shows no research effort, lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem, and is unlikely to be useful to future visitors.

Comment: VtC. Fixable, but off-topic in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

Removing something from a buffer is a costly operation. Normally, the buffer stays the same and some kind of pointer or index marker is used to mark the current logical start of the buffer. Depending on whether your buffer is an array, a std::vector or something completely different, this may be a `const TYPE*` of your array's type, or a simple `size_t` index or some `std::vector<TYPE>::const_iterator`.

Comment: I'm really new to C++ and would like to ask if you could expound your answer.

Comment: If you have a `char *buf` then `*(buf+3)` or `buf[3]` would be the byte at the position you need. Now you only need a way to use a variable instead of a fixed 3 and you can start reading through your buffer without changing it.